# How can I open Emacs on Mac OS X such that it is loaded with my $PATH?

Tags: macos, bash, emacs, applescript

I'm running Snow Leopard, and trying to run [Emacs](http://emacsformacosx.com/) such that when I start it up, the output of `(getenv "PATH")` is the same as the output in `Terminal.app` of `echo $PATH`.

In other words, I want to start up Emacs from `/Applications/Emacs.app` and have it start with my `$PATH`.  I haven't been able to figure out how to do this within emacs, or with how I start emacs up.  So I've spent most of my effort trying to come up with a shell script that I can wrap with something like [Platypus](http://www.sveinbjorn.org/platypus) or [Appify](http://sixohthree.com/1314/shell-scripts-as-applications-in-mac-os-x).

So the closest thing I have right now is:

```
echo MYPASSWD | sudo -S -u USERNAME -i nohup /Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs > /dev/null &
```

which fails because it seems that nohup throws away my $PATH, despite the `-i` flag.  The following does not throw away my `PATH` but open a superfluous `Terminal.app`:

```
echo MYPASSWD | sudo -S -u USERNAME -i open /Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs > /dev/null &
```

I've tried running this through `do shell script` in an AppleScript, also to no avail.

Am I missing something basic?  It doesn't seem like this should be hard.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a little elisp a while ago to parse the output of env and apply it to the Emacs environment because I didn't want to maintain a plist.  The code's at http://paste.lisp.org/display/111574.

Answer (score 2):

GUI applications are not launched by a traditional shell and do not inherit environment variables from the usual places like `.profile`, `.bash_profile`, etc.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPRuntimeConfig/Articles/EnvironmentVars.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002093-BCIJIJBH explains that `~/.MacOSX/environment.plist` is the place you probably want to add your favorite equivalent of $PATH.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem and here's how I worked around it.  I created ~/.bashrc and populated it with:

```
source /etc/profile
source ~/.profile
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to export the PATH to the location of the .app so it would be something like this

export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/the/program

That should allow you to just type EMACS and it will start up.